# Trying to add a new text field retaining content from another field

Tags: jquery

Here's my code.. I have 2 separate things working correctly and now I want to integrate them. A text field that gets input from another field and a button to add new fields. When I add a new field I get a blank field but I want to match the filled in field..

I also have this on fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/miketrujillo/nV2tA/light/

html:

```
<input type="text" name="input" id="input" size="30" value="Your Name">
<input type="text" id="name" size="30" value="">

<a href="#" id="addScnt">Add A Box</a>

<div id="namess">
<p>
<label for="names">
</label>
</p>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
var $name = $("#name");

$("#input").keyup(function () {
$name.val(this.value);
});

$(function () {
var scntDiv = $('#namess');
var i = $('#namess p').size() + 1;

$('#addScnt').live('click', function () {
    $('<p><label for="names"><input type="text" name="names_' + i + '" id="name" size="30" value=""></label><a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
    i++;
    return false;
});

$('#remScnt').live('click', function () {
    if (i > 2) {
        $(this).parents('p').remove();
        i--;
    }
    return false;
});
});
```

In the initial box I have id="name" and it works but it doesn't work on the new box. I also tried adding the keyup function into the click function but nothing useful there.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing:

`<input type="text" name="names_' + i + '" id="name" size="30" value="' + $name.val() + '">`

However, if you want the new text field(s) to update like the original, you should look at some other jQuery functions like `.each()`

Comment: Thanks I ended up adding a new var for the input and doing...
<input type="text" name="names_' + i + '" id="name" size="30" value="' + $input.val() + '">